# Merge multiple cascaded selects, with priority

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing cascaded SELECTs:

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c = 3
=> If nothing found, try: SELECT * FROM x WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c = 0
=> If nothing found, try: SELECT * FROM x WHERE a = 1 AND b = 0 AND c = 0
```

At least one of them has a result, but there can be results for all cases. I want to merge this logic and return one case only, the one with most given (!=0) conditions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could answer using a UNION query and NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c = 3

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM x
WHERE
  a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c = 0
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM x WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c = 3)

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM x
WHERE a = 1 AND b = 0 AND c = 0
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM x WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c = 3)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM x WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c = 0)
```

but a smarter solution would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE
  (a, b, c) = (
      SELECT a, b, c
      FROM x WHERE (a, b, c) IN ( (1,2,3), (1,2,0), (1,0,0) )
      ORDER BY (b=0) + (c=0)
      LIMIT 1
  )
```

I'm not sure this last one would have better performances. I would try which one is better.